# TFS 2018 Code Search

Tags: tfs

We have a new TFS 2018 installation and would like to use code search.  When I install the code search extension I get the following message:

> Search feature isn’t configured for your TFS instance. Configure Search through the TFS Configuration wizard and try again.

When I go to the Administration Console it says

> **Search is configured.**

Is there a step that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Please try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Check if you have installed the search service `Elasticsearch 5.4.1
  (elasticsearch-service-x64)` and make sure the service is running.
- Restart the TFS Server
- Remove the feature `Team Foundation Search Service`, then configure
  the Search feature again.

[image]